# Definition of Cantor Set without AC

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

You can see the original text that i thought AC is used here;

From Walter Rudin: Principles of Mathematical Analysis, 3rd ed., ISBN 0-07-054235-X, p.41-42.

> **2.44 The Cantor set** The set which we are now going to construct shows
>   that there exist perfect sets in $R^1$ which contain no segment.
>
> Let $E_0$ be the interval $[0, 1]$. Remove the segment $(\frac13,\frac23)$, and let $E_1$ be
>   the union of the intervals
>   $$[0,\frac13], [\frac23,1].$$
>   Remove the middle thirds of these intervals, and let $E_2$ be the union of the
>   intervals
>   $$[0,\frac19], [\frac29,\frac39], [\frac69,\frac79],[\frac89,1]$$
>   Continuing in this way, we obtain a sequence of compact sets $E_n$, such that
>   (a) $E_1\supset E_2  \supset E_3 \dots $;
>   (b) $E_n$ is the union of $2^n$ intervals, each of length $3^{-n}$.
>
> The set
>   $$P=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$$
>   is called the *Cantor set*. $P$ is clearly compact, and Theorem 2.36 shows that $P$
>   is not empty.
>
> No segment of the form
>   $$\left(\frac{3k+1}{3^m},\frac{3k+2}{3^m}\right)\tag{24},$$
>   where $k$ and $m$ are positive integers, has a point in common with $P$.
>   Since every segment $(\alpha,\beta)$ contains a segment of the form (24), if
>   $$3^{-m}<\frac{\beta-\alpha}6,$$
>   $P$ contains no segment.
>
> To show that $P$ is perfect, it is enough to show that $P$ contains no isolated
>   point. Let $x \in P$, and let $S$ be any segment containing $x$. Let $I_n$ be that interval
>   of $E_n$ which contains $x$. Choose $n$ large enough, so that $I_n\subset S$. Let $x_n$ be an
>   endpoint of $I_n$, such that $x_n\ne x$.
>
> It follows from the construction of $P$ that $x_n\in P$. Hence $x$ is a limit point
>   of $P$, and $P$ is perfect.
>
> One of the most interesting properties of the Cantor set is that it provides
>   us with an example of an uncountable set of measure zero (the concept of
>   measure will be discussed in Chap. 11).

---

I really didn't like the definition of Cantor set in my book (It defines cantor set by using AC$_\omega$), so i tried to construct it in more constructive way. (That is, without AC)

Let $E_n = [0,1]\setminus \bigcup_{k\in 3^n}(3k+1/3^{n+1}, 3k+2/3^{n+1})$.

(Exponentiation here is an ordinal exponentiation)

Let $C=\bigcap_{n\in \omega} E_n$.

I proved that $C$ is nonempty and compact, and $C$ contains no segment.

Now, I'm trying to prove that $C$ is perfect but there's a problem.

This is a lemma I made to prove this;
Let $T_n = \{3k/3^{n+1}, 3k+1/3^{n+1}, 3k+2/3^{n+1}, 3k+3/3^{n+1} \in [0,1] | k\in 3^n \}$.

'For every $n,m\in \omega$, if $n<m$, then $T_n\subset T_m$.'

Now, fix $x\in C$ and $0<r\in \mathbb{R}$.
Here, i have proved that there exists $m\in \omega$ such that $x$ is in some interval $I$ in $E_m$ and the $I\subset B(r,x)$. Now let $x'$ be an endpoint such that $x'≠x$.

By the lemma above, $x'\in E_n$ for every $m≦n$. However, i don't know how to prove this for $m>n$.

I tried it and proved that 'If $m>n$ and intersection of an interval $I_n$ in $E_n$ and an interval $I_m$ in $E_m$ is nonempty, the intersection is a set of exactly one endpoint of $I_m$ or $I_m \subset I_n$. (If one holds, the other does not hold)' too.
Here, I have no idea how to derive a contradiction that 'if $x\in I_m \cap I_n$, then $I_m \cap I_n$ is NOT a singleton' ($x\in C$)

Help

Comment: Try to see the fact that $C$ is the set of reals in $(0,1)$ having only $0$s and $1$s in their ternary expansion. Now, prove that there are no isolated points, and thus prove that $C$ is perfect.

Comment: I think you mean only zeros and twos.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Comment: I wonder what the definition *with* DC looks like. I can't think of one.

Comment: yeah, it would be interesting to ee that. @Katlus: please add a complete reference to the book: saying «my book» does not help in finding it :D

Comment: Edited :) AC$_\omega$

Comment: Mariano's question still stands: *what is your book?* And by "defines the Cantor set by $\mathrm{AC}_\omega$" do you mean the definition of the Cantor set as $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$? No $\mathrm{AC}_\omega$ here. This is nothing but the power set $P(\mathbb{N})$, which you know has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ with or without choice.

Comment: @t.b. Rudin PMA. The definition here is actually not precise, but since it defines $n+1$th set from $n$th set, i misunderstood it to be DC. I'm pretty sure that argument in this book uses AC$_\omega$.

Comment: I just noticed what was missing in my post.. Thanks..

Comment: @Katlus I've put [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers/4726#4726) the text from Rudin. ([Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/revisions/e9155b17-d12e-4222-aa47-e2b1e5c993f7/view-source) is the link directly to my revision.) If you find this a good idea, you can use it to post a new question, where you would indicate where precisely you think in the proof AC is used. In case you won't do this, please ping me here, so that I can edit the sandbox post to its original state or simply do it yourself.

Comment: @Martin Done. Anyway now i proved that it is perfect.(Let $F_n$ = $\bigcap_{x≦n} E_n$. Then, $\bigcap_{n\in \omega} F_n = \bigcap_{n\in \omega} E_n$. With this reault, i tried to prove it over again and it worked. I needed to check really many cases respectively though)

Comment: @Katlus I've copied the text from the sandbox (instead of the link), so that I can remove it from there (and other people can use the sandbox.)

Comment: No Axiom of Choice in any form is used in the construction of the Cantor Set.

Answer (score 10):

Converting my [above comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177428/definition-of-cantor-set-without-ac?noredirect=1#comment408526_177428) into an answer:

> While Rudin may be accused on hand-waving, I'm pretty sure that his basic idea uses no Choice principles.  Note that once $E_n$ is given, then the next set $E_{n+1}$ is determined, and not chosen out of some collection of possibilities  (or, to hedge, it is chosen out of a collection of exactly one possibility, but no Choice is required to do this).  This is a recursive construction (much like the definition of ordinal arithmetic is recursive).